# When writing a C++, if the source file is being saved, compile it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have this question : when I save a C++ source file in VsCode, I always need to run a task through [this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Qir.png), then : [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGDP2.png), translated to English would be : `"Compile this C++ active file using g++ compiler"`. I would like to know if there was a way to make sure that if the file is `saved` it will be also `compiled`. I tried to search everything possible but I really couldn't file something useful, plus I am not very familiar to .json language.

*Infos* :

**Code Editor** : `Visual Studio Code`

**Task Language** : `.json`

**Compiler** : `g++` **Version** `2.0.0`

**Terminal Used For Compiling** : `Windows PowerShell`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compila il file attivo",
      "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "compilatore: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
  ]
}
```

The normal procedure is to save the file, use the commands I put above, and then run the code from the terminal.

Comment: There are probably ways of making this work but I would suggest that this is a fairly bad idea: you should get in the habit of obsessively saving your code *all the time* (I save every few keystrokes!) and most of the time the state of the saved file will not be valid, compilable C++ code.

Comment: Sorry, I wonder a bit about your requirement. I'm not using VS Code but Visual Studio. If you built in Visual Studio all modified files are saved automatically before. (That makes sense to me.) But I may also save files (because I want to leave the desk or switch to another project) while knowing the current work in progress is neither compilable nor runnable. Thus an auto-build-on-save doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: maybe you want to do this in your 1 file projects, but if you get to the larger ones (hundreds of file) you don't want to computer to be grind to a hold and then you complain you can't edit files because the editor is so slow. What is the point of waiting a few tens of a second for the compiler to build your exe before you run the debugger of the exe, it is all done in the press of the run button (F5)

Comment: you are all right, thinking about it if I had an entire project this would be too uncomfortable, ty for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Sorry, my old approach didn't work and I noticed when re-reading the task.**

In order to automatically run the build task when a file is saved, you should use the *"file_watcher"* (instead of my previous implemention) setting in the *.vscode/settings.json* file:

```
{
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/**": true
  },
  "file_watcher": {
    "c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe": ["${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"]
  }
}
```

You will need to update the paths in the `file_watcher` setting to match your local configuration. You may also need to modify the build command and its arguments to match your project's requirements.

Comment: Ok, by `.vscode/settings.json` do you mean the `CTRL+SHIT+P` and `"Open User Settings"`? Because it says that the file should end after the `}` and if I paste it inside of it shows several errors

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+Shift+P works - then select Open User Settings as you described. If you see any errors after adding the content, it is likely due to a formatting issue. It's a good idea to double-check the syntax and indentation of the added lines to ensure they are correct.

Comment: And yes, the file *needs* to end after the last `}`! So everything else you got in your file needs to be integrated (and intended properly). There are .json editors online for that - for example!

Comment: Error in the line of `"c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe"`
`Invalid escape character in string.jsonc(261)`

Comment: Sorry, not my day.  :D
Backslashes need to be escaped: "c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"

Comment: Ty so much, the final problem is that `nothing seems to happen...` The `path` of `msys64` is correct. You said that it could have to do with the `build command`. What should I modify in the build command? Could it be that thing? Sorry if I continue to ask

Comment: Ok, but you still are watching for changes in the `tasks.json`? Furthermore, why are you trying to implement it from scratch - are you allowed to use plugins?

Comment: No I don’t think so , I only pasted what you have written to the settings.json file and nothing seems to happen but don’t worry. I will do some further researches on your file_watcher function and see what I got wrong on my PC, thank you so much for helping me :)